# How can I use LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode and still target .Net 4.5.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

I'd like to use GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode added in .Net 4.5.1 when running on a system with .Net 4.5.1 installed, but I can only require our users to have at least .Net 4.5.0 installed.

Is it possible to detect and use this feature at runtime?

My app is also NGen'ed upon installation, so I guess that will fail if I just add the code and surround it with a try/catch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Reflection to detect the presence of that feature and to use it. Do not statically reference members that are only present on 4.5.1.